Экспорт из Blender в Unity
Есть 3д модель в блендере, нужно использовать её в Unity. Проблема в том, что после добавления экспортированной модели в расширении .fbx в Unity все текстуры растягиваются, то есть Tiling сбивается и всегда устанавливается на значения 0.25, а так же ориентация текстур изменяется, прилагаю скриншоты.
UV карты проверял, ничего необычного, все верно и логично. Пробовал повернуть стену, применить трансформацию и повернуть ее назад, но так же никакого результата. 

